# Changes of Terminal look don't work anymore

Tags: terminal, osx, configuration

I got a mac laptop and have been using a home directory which is not under my name. After spending some time, I have set preferences and of course one day, I needed to change the home directory name to mine.

So I went into the users account settings, changed my home name, and moved the folder this way:

```
mv /Users/previous-name /Users/new-name
```

Everything worked fine, all my preferences are here, except for the terminal's. I tried to manually change the look and feel (with a theme, for instance the "Terminal > Preferences > Red Sands") but no change is taken into account. I still have black text with a white background.

I checked the `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files and made sure the variable `$HOME` was set instead of something like `/Users/previous-name`.

Opening a new terminal tab or window, relogging and restarting don't change anything.

Any thoughts, hints on how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I solved it. Instead of using the preferences from the toolbox `Terminal > Preferences`, I directly right-clicked on the terminal then chose `Show inspector > Settings`. Changing the theme to `Red Sands` there worked, I don't know why the first way did not, if someone knows why and would like to share the reason why. Anyway, problem solved!